# BigInteger undefined in React-Native using Aws Cognito SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, react-native, webpack, amazon-cognito

I read the issues related to Webpack as well as the official post but, I am still having the issue.

```
E/ReactNativeJS( 3520): Can't find variable: BigInteger
```

I am using AWS Cognito in a React-Native app with the following tree:

```
index.android.js
index.ios.js
webpack.config.js
android/
ios/
src/Aws.js
src/lib/jsbn.js
src/lib/jsbn2.js
src/lib/sjcl.js
src/lib/aws-sdk-2.4.11.min.js
src/lib/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js
src/lib/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js
```

My Aws.js is a custom wrapper of the existing Cognito functions.
In order to have basic functions working (such as register), my Aws.js is doing:

```
require('./lib/jsbn.js');
require('./lib/jsbn2.js');
require('./lib/sjcl.js');
require('./lib/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js');
require('./lib/aws-sdk-2.4.11.min');
require('./lib/amazon-cognito-identity.min');
```

However, the authentication function is sending me the very well-known bug of Undefined BigInteger in jsbn2.js.

I first installed the needed packages:

```
npm install imports-loader
npm install exports-loader
npm install script-loader
npm install webpack
```

I made my own webpack.config.js:

var webpack = require('webpack');

```
const AWS_SDK_MAIN = './src/lib/aws-sdk-2.4.11.min.js';
const AWS_COGNITO_SDK_MAIN = './src/lib/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js';
const AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_MAIN = './src/lib/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js';

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: 'my-app.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
      'aws-sdk$': AWS_COGNITO_SDK_MAIN
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {test: require.resolve(AWS_COGNITO_SDK_MAIN), loader: 'exports?AWSCognito' },
    {test: require.resolve(AWS_SDK_MAIN),loader: 'exports?AWS',}
    ],
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.min\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map'
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      AWS: AWS_SDK_MAIN,
      AWSCognito: AWS_COGNITO_SDK_MAIN,
    }),
  ]
};
```

And finally ran `npm run build`.
No success.

I tried to use the official doc of Webpack but the code snippet is not compiling:

```
JsbnWrapper = require("./js/lib/utils/jsbn.js");
-> JsbnWrapper is undefined.
```

I guess that my webpack.config.js must have missing or incorrect fields...
Thank you very much!

Comment: React-Native doesn't use webpack. This looks like a ReactJS project.